# get a video frame using qt gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

I checked the video stream displayed well in qml video surface. now I want to get the video frame data to do something not bad thing. but, It seems not doing well until now... I made a simple pipeline like below for focus on a test.

```
nvarguscamerasrc - appsink
```

I used **QGst::Utils::ApplicationSink** to get a frame data. I referenced an example "[appsink-src](https://github.com/GStreamer/qt-gstreamer/blob/master/examples/appsink-src/main.cpp)"

```
/* making pipeline */
QGst::ElementPtr source, sink;
SubClassApplicationSink *appsink;

source = QGst::ElementFactory::make("nvarguscamerasrc");
sink = QGst::ElementFactory::make("appsink");
appsink = new SubClassApplicationSink();

// configure elements    
source->setProperty("sensor-id", n);
appsink->setElement(sink);
appsink->enableDrop(true);
appsink->setMaxBuffers(7654321);

m_pipeline->add(source, sink);
source->link(sink);
```

subclass of ApplicationSink implements some callbacks eos, preroll, sample.

and I prints logs some values in a buffer I got from the new sample.

the same outputs are repeated as callback function is called.

result: [start-end offsets are -1, no flags, memory count 1, memory size 1008]

I don't know why... How do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. the problem was a pipeline's composition. after put a "nvvidconv" element between "nvarguscamerasrc" and "appsink" then I could get video frames successfully.

I don't know why needs a nvvidconv element. but, It seems because of source's video type, "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)" which means using DMA buffers for performance reasons.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/what-is-the-meaning-of-memory-nvmm/180522